# Wordpress Website - Phone Number Keeps Changing?

Tags: wordpress

I have the weirdest problem. I built a website for a client in Australia about 2 years ago (i'm located in the USA). They told me that the phone number listed on their Wordpress website isn't their phone number. They hit 'refresh' and the phone number changes again, to something completely different. I can't reproduce this on my end. What could be causing this? The phone number is on the website in a number of places, all of it is hard-coded html (we're not calling it from elsewhere on the site). I checked for any weird users wondering if the site has been hacked, but there's nothing. Any clue how this could be happening? I'm completely stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is a Web Application Firewall (WAF) in front of the web server. The WAF masking the phone numbers. If my guess is right, than the solution is make an exception "Not to mask any phone number or email address" in the WAF for that website only.

I faced such kind of problem in my case and solved it in this way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! Is this something the client would need to do? I.e. it's not something I need to change with the actual website?

Comment: Yes, I think so. WAF do this kind of changing to prevent information leakage or privacy.

Comment: Thank you!! This would make a lot of sense. I'll mark your answer as correct; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It maybe a browser extesion that changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Check Google Tag Manager if you are using it as plugin. And then check Bonfire phone track inside it. Paused it, and see if the phone number issue is fixed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found the issue in the phone conversion tracking code, provided by Google Ads. I placed the tracking code in the head section.

Namely, Google is using a random, forwarding number in order to track call conversions. That's Google's way to track if a call is initiated after the user clicks on the advertisement.

I removed the tracking code and the issue was fixed.

For anyone facing a similar problem, see if you have some phone tracking code installed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).